# Is it possible to debug the ShareLinkTask using the emulator?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7-emulator

I'm using the [`ShareLinkTask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.sharelinktask%28v=vs.92%29) in an app I'm developing, however, on the emulator it doesn't appear to do *anything*, not even pretend to go through the motions. Is this the sign of a bug with my code, or is this just how the emulator behaves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the way the emulator works with this task.

From msdn

> Allows an application to launch a dialog that enables the user to share a link on the social networks of their choice.

The emulator does not have any social networks so nothing to share.